# How to write a Multiple SSH commands inside for loop by using HERE document

Tags: shell

```
for SERVER in `grep -i "ma" /home/fsgapp/Test/test_dat`
do
    printf "$SERVER\n"
    ssh fsgapp@$SERVER bash -T <<-'HERE'
    pwd
    cd /usr/jboss/
    pwd
    'HERE'
done
```

When I am trying to execute this script I am getting 
**line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file**

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `'` around HERE.

From the manual: 
 `If any characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.`

At least the delimiter at the end needs to be without quotes.